# RMS value in frequency domain ISO 10816-1

Tags: matlab, math, octave

I need to count Velocity RMS value in frequency domain. After filtering signals with  band-pass filter to receive signals in the frequency range between 10 and 1 kHz and use FFT to count spectrum, I got :

[image: FFT]

I have found equation RMS for a function over all time:

1)[image: equation]

but im not sure how to write it in matlab.
Parseval's theorem is equal to equation 1) from above ??

Parseval's theorem code from internet not sure that is correct:

> rms = sqrt(sum((abs(x)/length(x)).^2));

so i found on old topic and s1 wrote equation to count RMS like this:

> rms1 = sum(abs(FFTDATA /length(data)).^2)
>
> rms2 = sum(abs(FFTDATA .^2) / length(data)) / (length(data) )
>
> rms1=rms2

but

> rms=sqrt(rms1)

not sure witch rms comand from above is equal to --->1) or any of them

Comment: It is better to upload the images (please use the "image" icon). Besides, your question is not clear. What is "random code" ? A guess: is `/length(x)` at the right place ?

Comment: main quesition is are this two equation are similar to each other. Best option is use the 1-st one but i cant find any clue how to implement it in matlab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well RMS stands for Root Mean Square, so you are looking for the formula you wrote in LaTeX, thus `sqrt(rms1)`, `sqrt(rms2)`, or `rms`.

Note that unless you have complex values, the `abs()` calls are useless.

[Parseval's Theorem](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem) says that you may use the squared sum of your transform (in frequency domain) to get your sum (or integral) of squares, instead of that of the velocities untransformed (in time domain). So you don't have to transform back once you filtered the frequencies that are within the ISO 10816.

Note that Parseval's Theorem is about the sum (or integral) of squares, but not the complete RMS (you still have to divide by T and take the square root). Which might explain why various sources have different codes.

In short : use the formula with `sqrt(rms1)`

> rms = sqrt((abs(FFTDATA)/length(data)).^2);